# SimpleDateFormat doesn't work

Tags: java

I'm trying to do something with a SimpleDateFormat, but after I read the Javadoc, I only got more confused. I want two methods, one for the timezone and one for the current time and date. My format should look like this:

```
Time Zone: GMT +01:00
Time and Date: Wednesday 17/04/2013, 20:38:34
```

I took code from the internet once for time. That worked fine:

```
    private String getFormattedTime() {
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");        

        return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

    }
```

This will output: 20:41:34

Now for my other format, I tried something like this (I wasn't completely done yet):

```
private static String getFormattedDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEEE DD/MM/yyyy, HH:mm:ss");      

    return sdf.format(cal);

}

private static String getTimeZone() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("z");       

    return sdf.format(cal.getTimeZone());

}
```

If you'd run this code, you get an IllegalArgumentException at the first `return` line.

It seems like the Javadocs don't give any example on how to use this.

Comment: On what line are those exceptions happening? (and you can limit the EEE... to just 4 EEEE to get the full form)

Comment: The "Date and Time" patters table mentioned at [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) should help you out, no? Also, some examples are mentioned under the "Examples" heading.

Comment: You'd be better served to include a stack trace than to say "_I got some InitializeException thrown out_..."  Being specific and including details tends to help when troubleshooting technical issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

SimpleDateFormat acts on Dates, not Calendars. To convert, use .getTime(), so your code should read:

```
private static String getFormattedDate() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEEEEEEE dd:MM:yyyy, HH:mm:ss");      

    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

}

private static String getTimeZone() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("z");       

    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());

}
```

However, using [joda](http://joda-time.sf.net) is probably a better way to go for reasons I could write a PhD thesis on.

Comment: And if you just want the current date and time you might as well use `new Date()`

Comment: Ok, that was working indeed. I wouldn't have thought of that, because the method name getTime() is pretty confusing, like it would only return the current time...

Comment: Well, I only need it for like one time, and hopefully it never happens at all (it will be used in an exception handler), so its a bit overloaded to import a whole new API into it.